# Why I can not pull the docker image that is public in dockerhub?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I built a Docker image and pushed it to Docker Hub with the latest tag. It appears to be public on Docker Hub, but I am unable to pull the image on my remote machine. I receive the following error:

```
Failed to pull image "sayinmehmet47/kitapkurdu-backend": rpc error: code = NotFound desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/sayinmehmet47/kitapkurdu-backend:latest": no match for platform in manifest: not found
```

Actually this was the command I use while build and push process

```js
 docker build -t sayinmehmet47/kitapkurdu-backend:latest .
```

```js
 docker push sayinmehmet47/kitapkurdu-backend:latest
```

This is a image from the dockerhub also

[image]

I don't understand why it can't be pulled. It's still public and can be verified at this [link](https://hub.docker.com/r/sayinmehmet47/kitapkurdu-backend).

this is also my remote machine in rancher try to pull it with this yaml file

```js
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend-deployment
  namespace: kitapkurdu
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: backend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: backend
          image: sayinmehmet47/kitapkurdu-backend
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
```

But when I use another image from dockerhub, that I created in same way, the remote machine accept it and get he image. See that one works well when pull it

**docker pull sayinmehmet47/event-bus**

So I got this error. I guess it can not find the image in the dockerhub.
[image]

Comment: This iis an  `arm` image. If I had to guess, I would say you try to pull from an non-`arm` system. Pulling the image by its digest (`podman pull docker.io/sayinmehmet47/kitapkurdu-backend@sha256:d886311782470fd65c1090b8e6ee667a6692101ecd5a275c7c4a0d480ddf38fe`) works.

Comment: @Turing85 this mean is it public now ?

Comment: I can pull it. I am not logged in. Therefore, it is public, yes.

Comment: @Turing85 what do you mean to use non-arm system. I need to use this public image name in my yaml file. But I dont know how can I do that in this case

Comment: Is the machine you are building the image the same as the machine you are pulling?

Comment: @donefoaiur it is in a remote machine in rancher.

Comment: @sayinmehmet47 are you on a mac M1 or M2? Have you built the image on said mac?

Comment: @Turing I am in mac M1 in my local machine, but I am using this image in remote machine, i attached it on the question again. But I dont know if you asking about the machine in rancher ?

Comment: It seems that the architecture doesn't match. You are building image for `linux/arm64/v8` but the machine on `rancher` is not that architecture. I'd try building and pulling on the same machine.

Comment: Well there is your problem. The M1 uses an `arm` processor and therefore produces `arm` images. The cluster, I presume, uses `x86_64` processors.

Comment: yes exacly it build it as arm. But I need it x86_64. But how should I use my command to build the image and pushing it to dockerhub other than using arm ?

Comment: Well that is a whole another question on it's own. But this might help you; https://www.docker.com/blog/multi-arch-images/

Comment: Take a look at [buildx (`github.com`)](https://github.com/docker/buildx). But the easier way would probably be to build the image on an `x86_64`-base machine.

Comment: @Turing85 I have some repos in dockerhub that I created in a some way. They can be reach and pull. Why I need buildx for this case. Take a look in this image I have in docherhub.
docker pull sayinmehmet47/event-bus:latest


 I dont remember I did any other configuration to create it in x86_64. But my last created images can not be pull. I am sure my old images in docherhub working well without this arm issues

Comment: Looking at the images under your dockerhub account, they are all `arm`-based, i.e. they have all "the same issue".

Comment: @Turing85 I can't pull `kitapkurdu-backend` but I can pull `event-bus` and they're the same arch. That's weird.

Comment: @doneforaiur this is actually the issue that confuse me :)

Comment: @sayinmehmet47 could you update the question so that it reflects the real issue?

Comment: Wait... you can pull one, but not the other, from one and the same machine?

Comment: @Turing85 actually in my m1 machine I can pull all of them. But my remote machine can not pull all of them. My remote machine can pull the "event-bus" one but can not pull the "kitapkurdu-backend". But they are created in the same way

Comment: Then I have no Idea what is going on.

Comment: I can pull it by giving it's digest by the way; `docker pull sayinmehmet47/kitapkurdu-backend@sha256:d886311782470fd65c1090b8e6ee667a6692101ecd5a275c7c4a0d480ddf38fe` works both for `kitapkurdu-backend` and `event-bus`. Similar to Turing's first reply. This is really weird behaviour.

Comment: Also, this might be related; https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/1925#issuecomment-873227828 Seems like an unresolved issue. Tüh. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These images are not built the same:

```
$ docker buildx imagetools inspect sayinmehmet47/kitapkurdu-backend:latest
Name:      docker.io/sayinmehmet47/kitapkurdu-backend:latest
MediaType: application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json
Digest:    sha256:c0d3a9b3ba06dd86dee9d529e5f20aa8011ed291de0ac00a0334fcdbc8a79e40
           
Manifests: 
  Name:        docker.io/sayinmehmet47/kitapkurdu-backend:latest@sha256:d886311782470fd65c1090b8e6ee667a6692101ecd5a275c7c4a0d480ddf38fe
  MediaType:   application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json
  Platform:    linux/arm64
               
  Name:        docker.io/sayinmehmet47/kitapkurdu-backend:latest@sha256:1b2d6e473aee211006bb38f40c54dd959738500fcd731f772ffb4f4062b12b6c
  MediaType:   application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json
  Platform:    unknown/unknown
  Annotations: 
    vnd.docker.reference.digest: sha256:d886311782470fd65c1090b8e6ee667a6692101ecd5a275c7c4a0d480ddf38fe
    vnd.docker.reference.type:   attestation-manifest

$ docker buildx imagetools inspect sayinmehmet47/event-bus
Name:      docker.io/sayinmehmet47/event-bus:latest
MediaType: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json
Digest:    sha256:df6e170dc4bb85b2f952e3ac0b0131a52d2fb93e25f3a34d444067427d70c9d4
```

What's happening in the `sayinmehmet47/kitapkurdu-backend:latest` image is that buildkit is attaching SLSA provenance as a second image with the `unknown/unknown` platform. Since the manifest with that is now a multi-platform manifest, runtimes look for their platform in the manifest list, and if not found, they fail to run the image.

For `sayinmehmet47/event-bus`, it is a simple image, not a manifest list (OCI index), so runtimes will attempt to execute it without verifying the platform.

You can disable provenance in the buildx build to disable the `unknown/unknown` images and fall back to a single platform image that should work with most runtimes:

```
docker buildx build --provenance=false ...
```

However, a better solution would be to build images to run on multiple platforms with:

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 ...
```

You will see a performance hit on the build, particularly if it's implemented with qemu emulation of the CPU instead of the compiler cross compiling.